# is the below language TSQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

We have an application which has some Stored procs written in below way.I tried googling but not able to find which language it is written.

declare @tbl__Paginate_exZVPE5724 table (i__SeqNo integer identity(1,1), p1 int)

__setup:

```
set nocount on

set     @i__rc                = 0
set     @i__Obj_AccessAllow   = 0
set     @i__pagex_FromRow     = 0
set     @i__pagex_ToRow       = 0
set     @i__pagex_PageSize    = 0
```

__main_body:

```
-- Set username for CFR
EXECUTE USP_Core_CFR_SetUserName @vc__usr__name_CFR


/*  define macro for users in audience                                                */
/*  define the fields                                                                 */
/*  sequence of columns matter for desc being ntext.                                  */
/*  define the PK SQL                                                                 */
/*  define the where SQL
```

Any help on understanding above code(__setup:,__main_body:) is much appreciated .Also an example using setup and mainbody will help understand this much better

Comment: yes this is most likely tsql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it is tsql but with a weird way of declaring stuffs...

__setup is just setting variables to some default value could have been done using

@DECLARE @i__rc     INT= 0 as well

and

__main_body is executing a storedprocedure with the name

**USP_Core_CFR_SetUserName** and a variable **@vc__usr__name_CFR**

Comment: Thanks ganes,will it be possible to give one example of sample stored proc using set up and main body

Comment: seems like there is a GOTO section in your script which you are missing to mention here

Comment: so if goto condition is met the control will jump to that specific section i.e either __setup: or __main_body:

Comment: Karthik,Can you please provide one sample storedproc using this for better understanding

Comment: the example here should help you understand http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180188.aspx